# Yii2 + AngularJS in a single application - how?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, yii2

I have experience with both [Yii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii) 2 and [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS), but separately. I have two questions:

Is it possible to use **AngularJS in Yii 2's view**? I am asking *possible* instead of *feasible*, because I think the problem may have arrived at routing.

Also, is it fair enough (for performance) to use Yii 2 and AngularJS together? (Both are MVC so for modular, manageable code.)

I searched for a long time, but I was unable to find any proper resource. What is the explanation!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**YES**, you can use **AngularJS** in **Yii 2** views after implementing a different rooting approach. Here is [a tutorial to start with](http://blog.neattutorials.com/angularjs-yii2-part-1-routing/).

But **NO**, I don't recommend doing so (while both **Yii 2** and **AngularJS** are great frameworks with native support of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)). So the proper way is to use **AngularJS** to build your *frontend* and use **Yii 2** just to provide [a server API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html). Here is a good structure to do so:

> *Structure by @AlekseiAkireikin from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744215/yii2-directory-structure-with-angular-js#answer-28749404)*

```
   project/
     backend/        // Yii 2 application
       web/          // Public visible backend folder
         index.php   // Entry point
       config/
       controllers/
       models/
       ...
     frontend/
       app/          // Your AngularJS application here
         css/        // Styles (.less or .css)
         img/        // Images
         lib/        // Third-party libraries such as jQuery or AngularJS
         js/         // .js files (controllers, services, etc.)
         partials/   // Templates (.html)
         index.html
       tests/        // AngularJS tests
       node_modules/
       ...
```

The [Yii RESTful API framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) will provide a clean [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) which can communicate with your built-in **AngularJS** application or maybe a future mobile app or even providing *resources and/or services* to other websites or software. If you care about performance then go with both and use REST. A well-structured RESTful application is great to easily build a good *caching* system with a flexible strategy behind. You can even host your backend and database on a server (like [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud)) providing only *JSON (and/or XML)* data for minimum bandwidth use, and having your frontend stored on an optimized [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (like Amazon S3 or other CDN provider) with lower cost and faster answers.

Here are two examples implementing AngularJS and Yii 2 within REST: [this](https://github.com/githubjeka/angular-yii2) and [this](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps).